# Encryption and Decryption of a text

Tags: vb.net, encryption

I have tried using the following code to divide a string into equal arts each of 2 letters but it was useless:

```
  Dim twoLetterWords = "The quick fox jumped over the lazy dog".
       Select(Function(c, i) New With {.Char = c, .Index = i}).
       GroupBy(Function(x) CInt(Math.Floor(x.Index / 2))).
       Select(Function(g) String.Join("", g.Select(Function(x) x.Char)))
```

And also I tried the following:

```
       Dim n As Integer

    Dim sasa(69) As String

    For i As Integer = 0 To sasa.Length - 1
        sasa(i) = "das"

    Next

    For i As Integer = 0 To RichTextBox1.TextLength - 2 Step 2
        For x As Integer = 0 To sasa.Length - 1
            n = i + 2
            sasa(x) = RichTextBox1.Text.Substring(i, 2)


            For z As Integer = 1 To 3
                RichTextBox2.Text = RichTextBox2.Text
            Next z
       Next x
    Next i
```

But that was in vain too. So, What is the thing I was mistaken in it? Or is there any other way to do the same thing I want to do ?

Comment: Are you experimenting with simple encryption, or do you actually have data you want to protect? If its the latter, stop immediately, and pick an established solution that .NET provides.

Comment: be careful adding arbitrary values to character codes, you may end up with unprintable characters, unless that is what you were aiming for, usually there is some kind of range check.

Comment: @YannRamin what are the established solution that .NET provides?

Comment: @Pow-Ian that's what I want :)

Comment: My spidey-sense is tingling... *please* don't develop your own custom "encryption". Just don't.

Comment: Why what? Why not develop your own "encryption" routines?

Comment: @NikBougalis Yes, Why not develop my"encryption" routines ?

Comment: See my answer as to why.

Answer (score 1):

In answer to your comment on why you should not develop your own "encryption" routines the short answer is this:

Cryptography is difficult and is equal parts science and art. People with degrees in computer science and mathematics who specialize in cryptography have produced bad solutions and they had the theoretical background to know better. That should be caution and warning enough.

You don't even have that; you are clueless and the chances are overwhelming that whatever you do end up developing will be *horrible*. And there's enough horrible encryption code out there already.

Sorry to be blunt, but that's reality.

For more, take a look at http://www.schneier.com/blog/archives/2011/04/schneiers_law.html.

Comment: Don't be sorry at all. Actually, I know some of what you have said. Let me tell you the whole story: I am 16 years old & just started programing 2 years ago & I liked that very much. I started to have courses in VB.NET, ASP.NET, SQL, Access & many others. When I started that app a year ago it was like what you have seen above then I kept developing on it (it's now different than above code). I kept thinking about how the decipher might break my code, once I find a bug in my code I solve it & so on. Anyway, I'm just doing that just to learn new things (I won't sell it to Microsoft tomorrow)

Comment: First of all awesome and congrats on getting started with programming. It's really fun. I still think that you should avoid rolling your own encryption even to "learn", especially without guidance, because I don't think that you will really learn anything doing it that way. Instead I *strongly* suggest that you pick up the book "Applied Cryptography" by Bruce Schneier and start from there. It will give you a lot of good information - both theory and practice - and is a great way to explore the field while hopefully learning from mistakes other made and avoiding them.

Comment: Sure I'll take your advice, But what field you may recommend me to start with? Can I take your e-mail or your Facebook account so that we can communicate together and I can learn more from you?